# Select feature based on both its own attributes and another feature's attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, select, time

I have two points within a polygon, each representing a specific event with a date (listed as 120101 and 120719). The polygon itself represent an event for an extended time period (start: 120626 and end: 130114). I'm working in ArcMap 10.2.

What I want to do is to be able to select the point that falls with the polygon's time period by use of query. How do I do that?

Here's a picture showing the setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here are the steps.

1. Select features from polygon layer using Selection -> Select by Attributes.
2. Now select features from point layer using Selection -> Select by location. Click the check box "use selected features" at the bottom of source layer.
3. At last select feature from point layer again using Selection -> Select by Attributes and change your Method "Select from current selection".

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

AN UPDATE:

I managed to solve the problem by adding the start and end date attributes from the polygons to the points attribute table. This was done by 'Join by spatial location'

Then I just put up a query within 'Select by attributes' that looked like this:

"poly_start" < "point_time" AND "point_time" < "poly_end"

Anyways, thanks again *iRfAn*, hopefullt someone else with the same problem in the future can use this thread as a help.

//Joachim